# Parsing JSON dictionary with multiple arrays with NSJSONSerialization does not result in NSDictionary or NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to parse a JSON dictionary in the form of:

```
{
"bible": {
    "book": [
        {
            "bookName": "Genesis",
            "chapter": [
                {
                    "chapterNum": "1",
                    "verse": [
                        {
                            "verse": "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.",
                            "verseNum": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "verse": "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.",
                            "verseNum": "2"
                        },
```

I am having difficulties getting to the proper data within this structure. My goal is to create a Verse managed object that has a verseNum, verse (the text), chapterNum, and bookName properties.

I need help creating the object. Currently, when I create the NSDictionary using NSJSONSerialization, I only obtain one dictionary, with a single NSCFString:

```
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kjv"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];

    NSDictionary *bible = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                            error:&err];

    for (NSDictionary *book in [bible valueForKey:@"bible"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", book);
    }
```

The console output simply reads: book

Comment: NSLog the object (an NSDictionary) you get back from NSJSONSerialization.  You will see that it strongly resembles the original JSON, and that the "bible" element of the outermost dictionary is another dictionary containing an element named "book".  When you do the `for` loop you're looping through the keys in the "bible" dictionary, and the only one there is "book".  Now if you were to extract that element you'd find that it was an array, and it's elements were dictionaries corresponding to the books of the Bible.  (You should NSLog *every* step along the way until you understand this.)

Comment: Hint:  NSLog the result from `[bible valueForKey:@"bible"]`.

Comment: And, when looking at an NSLog, understand that the *outermost* bracketing characters are `()` for a dictionary and `[]` for an array.

Comment: (Oops -- `()` for array and `{}` for dictionary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
id JSONResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData 
                                                  options:0 
                                                    error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", error);
    return;
}

// Should be an NSDictionary or NSArray
NSLog(@"JSON response: %@", [JSONResponse description]);

NSArray *books = [JSONResponse valueForKeyPath:@"bible.book"];

for (NSDictionary *book in books) {
    NSLog(@"%@", book);
    NSString *bookName = [book valueForKey:@"bookName"];
    NSArray *chapters = [book valueForKey:@"chapter"];
    // loop through the chapters
    ...
    NSArray *verses = [book valueForKey:@"verse"];
    // loop through the verses
    ...
}
```

Comment: The console output for the description of the object is the entire JSON Dictionary. I'm still not sure how to parse out the desired properties from this. The JSONResponse variable is an NSDictionary with a single key value pair.

The valueForKeyPath does only print a single book at a time. To similarly get the chapter and verse would other arrays be `@"bible.book.chapter"` and `@"bible.book.verse"`? So to get each verse, I'd have to nest for loops for the book, chapter and verse arrays?

Comment: (The JSON *is* arranged rather illogically.)

Comment: Ok good, so now you know that it's an NSDictionary. So you can traverse it like any other NSDictionary. It's also common to traverse the dictionary and copy the data to custom model objects like Bible, Book, Chapter, Verse, etc. Then you can access it in the rest of your application in an easier way. These Model objects could be Core Data NSManagedObjects for example.

Comment: Wow. Getting how that was structured was really weird. Your answer was spot on and got me where I needed to go. Thanks Jesse!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your JSON document is an object (dictionary), containing one element named "bible". bible is itself a dictionary containing one element named "book". book is an array. The array elements are objects, with an item "bookName" containing a string, and another item "chapter" containing an array and so on. So:

```
NSDictionary* JSONResponse = ...
NSAssert ([JSONResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]);
NSDictionary* bible = JSONResponse [@"bible"];
NSAssert ([bible isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]);
NSArray* books = bible [@"book"];
NSAssert ([books isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);

for (NSDictionary* book in books)
{
    NSAssert ([book isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]);
    NSString* bookName = book [@"bookName"];
    NSArray* chapters = book [@"chapter"];
}
```

and so on.